# Public Health Epi - Apply custom function to date column without using dplyr::rowwise()

Tags: r

First of all - major thanks to the stackoverflow community. You've always been able to answer my questions without me asking a question. I'm finally stuck on writing a function and would appreciate any insights.

Background: I'm an epidemiologist working in viral respiratory surveillance. We usually look at data in terms of "seasons", which starts the Sunday of the first week in October and starts over the following year. For example season 2023-2024 started on 10/1/2023 and will end on 9/28/2024.

What I'm trying to do: The function below will work on a single date, or using `dplyr::rowwise()` in a dataframe, but is there a way I can apply the function to a column in a dataframe without using `dplyr::rowwise()`?

```
test_func <- function(date){
  
  if(class(date)!="Date"){
    stop("Input not in date format.")
  }
  
  year = as.numeric(strftime(date, "%Y"))
  days = date - as.Date(sprintf("%s-10-01", year))
  
  oct_start = date - days
  
  #1 = monday, 7 = sunday
  
  wkday = as.numeric(strftime(oct_start, "%u"))
  
  #10/1/2022 saturday, starts 10/2/2022
  #10/1/2021 friday, starts 10/3/2021
  #10/1/2020 thursday, starts 10/4/2020
  
  if(wkday %in% 1:6){
    season_start = oct_start - wkday
  } else{
    season_start = oct_start
  }
  
  season_end = season_start + 364
  
  if(date < season_start){
    season_start = season_start - 364
    season_end = season_start + 364
  }
  
  year1 = as.numeric(strftime(season_start, "%Y"))
  year2 = as.numeric(strftime(season_end, "%Y"))
  
  return(paste(year1,year2, sep = "-"))
}
```

`test_func(as.Date("2024-09-28"))` yields "2023-2024", which is correct.

If I apply same function to vector of dates, I get the condition has length > 1 error.

`date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2023-10-01"), to = as.Date("2023-10-31"), by = 1)`
`test_func(date)`

UPDATE: Thanks for the responses, especially the one about maintaining vectorization. Dates get a little wonky with ifelse, so I had to introduce a helper function that maintains the class. Here's my final function:

```
assign_season <- function(date){

  if(class(date)!="Date"){
    stop("Input not in date format.")
  }

  init_week_num = OCepi::to_mmwr_date(OCepi::week_ending_date(date), "week")

  adjust = ifelse(init_week_num %in% c(40:53), init_week_num - 40, 40 - init_week_num) * 7

  # init_season_start = OCepi::week_ending_date(date + adjust) - 6
  init_season_start = safe.ifelse(
    init_week_num %in% c(40:53),
    OCepi::week_ending_date(date - adjust) - 6,
    OCepi::week_ending_date(date + adjust) - 6
  )

  season_start = safe.ifelse(date < init_season_start, init_season_start - 364, init_season_start)

  season_end = season_start + 363

  year1 = as.numeric(strftime(season_start, "%Y"))
  year2 = as.numeric(strftime(season_end, "%Y"))

  return(paste(year1,substr(year2,3,4), sep = "-"))
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `if(1:10 == 5) print("a")`; `if` expects an input of length one to be checked.

Comment: You need to make sure that all the parts of your function support "vectorization"; that is if you pass in a vector, you get a vector out. The `if` statement breaks that rule. The `if` can only check one value at a time. Instead use something like `ifelse` to preserve vectorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric vectors can be multiplied with a boolean,

```
> c(1, 2, 3)*c(c(1, 2, 3) %in% 1:2)
[1] 1 2 0
```

which we can exploit in your function.

```
test_func <- function(date) {
  if (class(date) != "Date") {
    stop("Input not in date format.")
  }
  year <- as.numeric(strftime(date, "%Y"))
  days <- date - as.Date(sprintf("%s-10-01", year))
  oct_start <- date - days
  ## 1=monday, 7=sunday
  wkday <- as.numeric(strftime(oct_start, "%u"))
  ## 10/1/2022 saturday, starts 10/2/2022
  ## 10/1/2021 friday, starts 10/3/2021
  ## 10/1/2020 thursday, starts 10/4/2020
  ## FIX 1 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  # if (wkday %in% 1:6) {
  #   season_start <- oct_start - wkday
  # } else {
  #   season_start <- oct_start
  # }
  working_day <- wkday %in% 1:6
  season_start <- oct_start - wkday*working_day
  ## +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  season_end <- season_start + 364
  ## FIX 2 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  # if (date < season_start) {
  #   season_start <- season_start - 364
  #   season_end <- season_start + 364
  # }
  pre_season <- date < season_start
  season_start <- season_start - 364*pre_season
  season_end <- season_start + 364*pre_season
  ## +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  year1 <- as.numeric(strftime(season_start, "%Y"))
  year2 <- as.numeric(strftime(season_end, "%Y"))
  return(paste(year1, year2, sep="-"))
}
```

##### Usage

```
test_func(as.Date("2024-09-28"))
# [1] "2023-2024"

date <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("2023-12-24"), to=as.Date("2024-01-10"), by=1) 
test_func(date)
#  [1] "2023-2023" "2023-2023" "2023-2023" "2023-2023" "2023-2023" "2023-2023" "2023-2023"
#  [8] "2023-2023" "2023-2024" "2023-2024" "2023-2024" "2023-2024" "2023-2024" "2023-2024"
# [15] "2023-2024" "2023-2024" "2023-2024" "2023-2024"
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I hadn't though of that - thank you! Here's where I landed:

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this unmodified would be:

```r
# vector of dates
date <- seq.Date(
    from = as.Date("2024-09-25"),
    to = as.Date("2024-10-03"),
    by = 1
)

# create data.frame
df <- data.frame(date = date)

# base
df$out <- sapply(df$date, test_func)
```

```
> df
        date       out
1 2024-09-25 2023-2024
2 2024-09-26 2023-2024
3 2024-09-27 2023-2024
4 2024-09-28 2023-2024
5 2024-09-29 2024-2025
6 2024-09-30 2024-2025
7 2024-10-01 2024-2025
8 2024-10-02 2024-2025
9 2024-10-03 2024-2025
```

With dplyr:

```
# dplyr
df <- dplyr::mutate(df, out = sapply(date, test_func))
```